# The request failed with an empty response. when calling third party server

Tags: c#, cognos, cognos-bi

I am trying to integrate cognos BI server with console application when I tried to connect to server I am getting error state as 'The request failed with an empty response.'

```
credentialXML.AppendFormat("<namespace>{0}</namespace>", "");
credentialXML.AppendFormat("<username>{0}</username>", "username");
credentialXML.AppendFormat("<password>{0}</password>", "Password");
credentialXML.Append("</credential>");

//The csharp toolkit encodes the credentials
string encodedCredentials = credentialXML.ToString();
xmlEncodedXML xmlEncodedCredentials = new xmlEncodedXML();
xmlEncodedCredentials.Value = encodedCredentials;
searchPathSingleObject[] emptyRoleSearchPathList = new searchPathSingleObject[0];
cBICMS.logon(xmlEncodedCredentials, null);
```

Comment: Use Fiddler to debug your request.

Comment: I tried with fiddler I got 302 status and after this getting same error in console.

Comment: 302 is a redirect. Have you got any response body? I suspect you need to concentrate on checking the receiver (Cognos).

Comment: Kind of a long shot because this is clearly not all the code, but are you including the opening `<credential>` tag in your credential XML?  Also, what does your connection line look like for `cBICMS`?